# Comparing specific data from string within cells by locating via unique parameters

Tags: vba, excel

I have a string that often looks like this:

X-POTATO-2D-AB3F-N

It will always be in that format, and I want to compare "AB3F"to another string of four characters. Here's the catch, certain values in this string may change in length, so I cannot compare simply "the first four of the last 6 characters"

What will always stay the same is the number of dashes. Always at least 4 in total (on rare occasions 5), and the string that I want to compare will always be between the last two. Is it possible to use these to isolate the 4 or 5 characters that I want to compare?

I know Stack overflow doesn't like vague questions. Sorry! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

http://excel.tips.net/T003324_Finding_the_Nth_Occurrence_of_a_Character.html

Essentially, this formula:

`=FIND("¬",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","¬",4))`

Where A1 is your string. This will return the position of the 4th "-". (Because `substitute` replaces the 4th "-" with a "¬", which is unlikely to appear in the code, and `find` then finds the "¬")

Edit, just realised that the 4th group may also have more than 4 digits, so you could retrieve it with the overcomplicated:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("¬",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","¬",3))+1,FIND("¬",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","¬",4))-FIND("¬",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","¬",3))-1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to learn this and then try to implement it. I'll get back to you if it works! :D

Comment: I really appreciate it!

Comment: What about the occasion where there are five dashes?

Comment: This will return the string between the 3rd and 4th dashes in all cases, It would be easy enough to modify based on substituting out the hyphens and comparing the length of the original string with the substituted string.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned there could be four or five hyphens, and that your desired value will always be between the last two, I suggest the following:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",99)),198),99))
```

- Replace each hyphen with 99 spaces (much longer than the longest substring)
- The Right most 198 characters will surely have the last two substrings
- Left (...,99) will surely return the first of those two
- Trim to get rid of the extra spaces

This approach will work with four or five hyphens.

If you are going to use this in a Macro, the following code will return the "Next To Last" hyphen-delineated substring within a string:

```
Dim V As Variant
V = Split(S, "-")
NextToLast = V(UBound(V) - 1)
```

Comment: I need to look into this some more. Let me test on various fields in my sheet. Im using this with a macro, and this seems more robust. Ill get back to you.

Comment: @CodingNovice I will add code that you could use in a Macro